# Can you call AWS CDK in python without CLI?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Is it possible to run the AWS CDK lifecycle directly in python (or any other language), without using the cli? e.g.

**app.py**

```
    app = cdk.App()
    Stack(app, ..)
    app.synth()

    app.deploy()
```

**run python**

```
    python app.py   //instead of cdk deploy...
```

this could be useful to prepare temporary test scenarios.

Comment: See the open issue: [Programmatic Access of CDK CLI Capabilities](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/issues/300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's possible as of today:

#### Programatically synth templates without `cdk synth`?

Yes.  CDK's [testing constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html) work this way.  Tests assert against a programatically synth-ed template.

```py
template = Template.from_stack(processor_stack)

template.resource_count_is("AWS::SNS::Subscription", 1)
```

#### Programatically deploy apps without `cdk deploy`?

Not in the way the OP describes, but you can get close with  the CDK's CI/CD constructs. The [CDK Pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html) construct synths and deploys CDK apps programatically.  Build a pipeline that builds and tears-down a testing environment on each push to your remote repository.  Alternatively, a standalone [CodeBuild Project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild-readme.html) can be used with commands to `cdk deploy` an app and perform tests when triggered by an event.

Also worth mentioning is [cdk watch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/increasing-development-speed-with-cdk-watch/) for rapid local development iterations.  It automatically deploys incremental changes as you code.